# jquery css transform translate reset

Tags: jquery, css-transitions, css-transforms

I am trying to repeat a CSS transition when a button is pressed using JavaScript and jQuery.  The CSS the image is set:

```
.icon1-image {
position: absolute;
top: -105px;
left: 507px;
}
```

Then in a click function in a JS file I'm trying to translate '`icon-image`' location and then have it animate back to the original position in 2s.

So every time the button is click '`icon1Image`' is move over and down 507px and then animates back to the original position:

```
$icon1Image.css({
"-moz-transform":"translate(507px,507px)",
"-webkit-transform":"translate(507px,507px)",
"-ms-transform":"translate(507px,507px)",
"transform":"translate(507px,507px)",

"-moz-transition":'transform 0s ease-in',
"-webkit-transition":'transform 0s ease-in',
"-ms-transition":'transform 0s ease-in',
"transition":'transform 0s ease-in',

"-moz-transform":"translate(0px,0px)",
"-webkit-transform":"translate(0px,0px)",
"-ms-transform":"translate(0px,0px)",
"transform":"translate(0px,0px)",

"-moz-transition":'transform 2s ease-in',
"-webkit-transition":'transform 2s ease-in',
"-ms-transition":'transform 2s ease-in',
"transition":'transform 2s ease-in'

});​
```

Using this code the original transform seems to be ignored.  What is the correct method to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/owhqj9c3/1/

**CSS**
    .animation{animation: anim 2s ease-in;}

```
@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    transform:translate(507px,507px)
  }
  100% {
    transform:translate(0,0)
  }
}
```

JS

```
$(this).addClass("animation");
```

Comment: Two things with with. 1) for performance reasons I can't use keyframes and 2) the animation only happens once where I need to animation to reset and happen again every time the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use css `keyframes`, you can look into [`transitionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) or [jQuery `.delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/).

`transitionend` is an event which will trigger when a css transition ends. You could use it like so:

```
$button
.on('click', function(){

    $icon1Image
    .one('transitionend', function(){ // .one() triggers only once

        $(this).css({ /* reset css */ });

    })
    .css({ /* apply new css */ });

});
```

Using `.delay()`:

```
$button
.on('click', function(){

    $icon1Image
    .css({ /* apply new css */ })
    .delay(2000) //wait 2 seconds
    .css({ /* reset css */ });

});
```